# CSS Trouble adding border

Tags: jquery, css, sass, flexbox, css-selectors

i'm trying to add a black border to the text box on this code -

```
             <p class="line-item-property__field">
              <div style="clear:both">
  <label for="custom-text">Customise Text</label>
                </div>
  <input id="custom-text" type="text" name="properties[Custom Text]">
</p>
```

I've searched the internet and tried multiple things but i'm not good with this stuff i'm still learning.

Comment: *tried multiple things* --> where are they?

Answer (score 1):

You can use css like this:

```
#custom-text{
 border: solid black 2px; 
}
```

[working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sow1bem2/)

Comment: Hey but where do I insert that code sorry? I'm putting it below <input id="custom-text" type="text" name="properties[Custom Text]">

Comment: @RossGreene in css file

Answer (score 0):

For adding a border for element use border like this:

```
#custom-text {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code on your style section or css file.

```
#custom-text{
 border: 1px solid black; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#custom-text {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The CSS border properties allow you to specify the style, width, and color of an element's border.
add border to your input tag( or for custom-text id):

```
input{
border:1 px solid #000
}

#custom-text{
border:1 px solid #000
}
```